# Dynamically setting step counter to kendo chart in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, kendo-ui

How to set step counter dynamically if I am using Kendo Chart in MVC?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to step the counter dynamically based on the number of data points on an axis (the most common scenario) then you'll need to write some client side code. At the point your server side code executes to generate the chart you don't know how many points are going to be displayed on the chart - or at least you don't if you're using Ajax binding.

You should hook up a handler to the [databound](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart#events-dataBound) event of the chart, then set the [labels.step](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-categoryAxis.labels.step) property for the particular axis in that handler.

Here's an example: http://mikaelkoskinen.net/kendoui-dataviz-tips-and-tricks/